# Cordova - How to execute callback function twice in android

Tags: android, cordova, callback, cordova-plugins

I want to call callback function twice. Once it gets executed and another after other function executed. I have kept toast in second function, which is working fine but it's not calling callback function again.

```
private void triggerWid(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    Context context = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
     WidgetBuilder widgetBuilder = new WidgetBuilder()
            .setApiKey(LIQUIDPAY_API_KEY)
            .setApiSecret(LIQUIDPAY_SECRET_KEY)
            .setApplicationContext(context)
            .build();
    try {
        widgetBuilder.run(new WidgetInterface() {
            @Override
            public void onExit() {
                // result_status.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                // result_status.setText(R.string.done);
                CALLBACK_MESSAGE = "Done";
                callbackContext.success("Done"); // Want to call here but not working
                new Utils().showToast(context, "Widget Triggered");

            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.e("WIDGET ACCESS", e.getMessage());
        CALLBACK_MESSAGE = e.getMessage();
        callbackContext.error("Error");
    }
    callbackContext.success(CALLBACK_MESSAGE); // Getting called first
}
```

As you can see in the code, first time its working fine. But I want to call it next time also. May I know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.